# How to light up screen on iPhone with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, screen

Is it possible to light up the screen of an iPhone with Swift?
I do not want to unlock the screen, I just want to have the same effect as you would touch on the screen, that the lock screen appears.

I searched the UIDevice object but couldn't find any way right now.

Comment: Apple generally don't let you do stuff like this to prevent misuse. There might be a way to achieve it with remote notifications though

Comment: Okay thank you, I know the notification way, but just sending a notification does not fulfil the requirement. It's for a health application to attract the user to the phone for emergencies.
Just wondering why people give -1 and don't respond why.

Comment: I think it's possible to schedule a local notification for some point in the future from within your app, I imagine that's the way Apple would want you to attract the user's attention

Comment: Thank you for the reply Andi. Yes I already use this kind of attraction, but in my use case it causes not enough attention. But it seems I have to keep this solution :-/